# Install mysql client in docker image

Tags: php, mysql, docker

I am trying to build a docker image for php, which can handle database dumping in my mysql container. The problem is that it seems to install the mariadb version instead of the mysql version of the client. This gives me an error `mysqldump: unknown variable 'set-gtid-purged=OFF'`

The script that does the dumping is not one I can change, as it is part of the laravel core. It detects the server sql version to see if it should add that command or not. So I really need to have the right client version on my php image/container.

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM library/php:7.4-fpm

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y default-mysql-client
```

Comment: Why pile everything into one container? The idea behind containers is you'd make one *just* for dumping.

Comment: This is a MySQL 8.0 feature, so maybe it's installing an older version of the client?

Comment: @tadman Everything is in seperate containers, but as the dumping is running from php itself (CLI), I dont see any what of having it pass that command to another container.

Comment: Dumping's a pretty simple thing to replicate, mind you, so if you're really in a jam you might find another container that already does this, or you can bang one together pretty quickly. I have a feeling the base OS for that PHP image just doesn't have the latest MySQL and it's being given incompatible options.

Comment: You could also try a different PHP runtime container that may be more up-to-date. There's also the option of adding additional repositories to that installation (Debian? Ubuntu?) but that gets extraordinarily messy fast.

Answer (score 11):

I managed to find a solution. I decided to read through how the official mysql image is built, and implement the same solution here.

https://hub.docker.com/layers/mysql/library/mysql/latest/images/sha256-b589f11ab39a852fd13090aeb56314978c73a16d615e28ec148306889b67889f?context=explore

So adding in this, installed the needed client and everything works.

```
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 8C718D3B5072E1F5

RUN echo "deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ buster mysql-8.0" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y mysql-community-client
```

Comment: Thank you! I had found mysql-default-client, but not community...

Comment: As of Nov 2021, this has changed somewhat; the first RUN statement needs to be replaced by step 9 of https://hub.docker.com/layers/mysql/library/mysql/8.0/images/sha256-975b3b1a6df6bf66221d1702b76c4141a4cd09f93f22f70c32edc99a6c256fe8?context=explore

Answer (score 6):

If you build that image then run
`docker run -it <MyImageName> bash` you can kinda explore what is going on.

`apt show default-mysql-client`
shows the following so you are correct it is mariadb.

```
root@ff27370412ab:/var/www/html# apt show default-mysql-client
Package: default-mysql-client
Version: 1.0.5
Priority: optional
Section: database
Source: mysql-defaults
Maintainer: Debian MySQL Maintainers <pkg-mysql-maint@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Installed-Size: 10.2 kB
Depends: mariadb-client-10.3
Download-Size: 3532 B
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
Description: MySQL database client binaries (metapackage)
```

You can then run `apt search mysql` to find other packages you can use.

I glanced through a few of them but didn't find any that seemed like non maraidb. But you can add it to your apt repo using the following steps.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/

Comment: Your comment was fit perfect for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

As stated by @jeff-h above, the answer has slightly changed since November 2021:

```
RUN set -ex; \
# gpg: key 5072E1F5: public key "MySQL Release Engineering <mysql-build@oss.oracle.com>" imported
    key='859BE8D7C586F538430B19C2467B942D3A79BD29'; \
    export GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)"; \
    gpg --batch --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys "$key"; \
    gpg --batch --export "$key" > /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mysql.gpg; \
    gpgconf --kill all; \
    rm -rf "$GNUPGHOME"; \
    apt-key list > /dev/null
```

The key difference here (pun intended) is the new keyserver address.

- Old: `ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net`
- New: `keyserver.ubuntu.com`

Edit; Added the new key from @jeff-h's comment below.

Comment: The new key is `859BE8D7C586F538430B19C2467B942D3A79BD29`

Comment: I'm getting "E: Unable to locate package mysql-community-client". I copied the entire docker file and got the same error. I'm using Mac M1, could it be that it's not available on ARM architecture? 
Here's the dockerfile I copied: https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/8.0/Dockerfile.debian

Comment: Exactly, seems there is no precompiled mysql client version for arm unfortunately :( https://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/dists/bullseye/mysql-8.0/